# Check cells in column value matches specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel, matching

Ok, so I am completely new to VBA and coding of any sort. So forgive me if this is an easy solution.

I am creating a spreadsheet based on grades in a class. What I need to do is see if the answers chosen by the students (a, b, c, d, e) match the answer key (which is in it's own row). However, the number of range is variable and depends on user input (i.e. the number of students and the number of answers varies for each assignment). [Attached image of example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvnf3.png)

My end goal is to convert the correct answers to read as 1 and incorrect to read as 0, with a total in the last column. So far, I am only able to get a singular cell to do this and haven't quite figured out the rest (everything I've tried for any sort of variable range returns an error).

Any suggestions would be wildly appreciated!

Comment: please look up a tutorial on loops, lastrow, lastcolumn etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sub procedure using arrays for processing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub answerNumbers()
    Dim vals As Variant, ans As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        ans = .Cells(8, "D").Resize(1, 5).Value2
        vals = .Range(.Cells(10, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7))

        For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            For j = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2)
                vals(i, j) = Abs(CBool(vals(i, j) = ans(1, j)))
            Next j
        Next i

        .Cells(10, "D").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, you are an absolute saint!! Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.

Comment: Last question for this, I promise. If the data set was variable in terms of columns (in this case the number of questions), how could I make this work for a dynamic range? Right now it will work for up to 5 questions and I can alter it to work for as many questions as I need I just have to adjust it manually for each dataset. Having it be dynamic and more or less self regulating would be much easier. I'm sure it's simple, but I am still very new to this. Any advice is wildly appreciated